# What python's Pandas data struts used for?

Tags: python, pandas

There are at least four data struts in pandas.

->Slice
->DateFrame
->DateMatrix
->Panel

What are the use cases for these. The documents seem to highlight slice and DataFrame.
Please give examples of use cases. I know where the doc is located.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 3 main data structures are Series (1-dimensional), DataFrame (2D), and Panel (3D) (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html). A DataFrame is like a collection of Series while a Panel is like a collection of DataFrames. In many problem domains (statistics, economics, social sciences, ...) these are the 3 major kinds of data that are dealt with.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/overview.html

Also, DataMatrix has been deprecated. In pandas >= 0.4.0, DataMatrix is just an alias for DataFrame.